# Can i check multiple function call using jest/enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, jest-enzyme

I have onchange callback(been called from child to parent) function in one of the component
i was trying to simulate onchange function as shown but i am getting error as
'getchangeChecbox' is not a function

childcomponent

```
<checkbox
label="checkbox input"
value={checkBoxInitalState}
onChange={e => { toggleCheckbox(e);  selectOption(e?'A':'B') }}
```

testcase

```
checkBoxValue.props().onChange(false)
output.update()
```

Error

```
toggleCheckbox is not a function
```

how do i simulate onchange in this scenario?how to check selectoption value(selectoption is a function)

Comment: The error tells you that `toggleCheckbox` is not a function, so the `onChange` has been called. Can you show more code from your ChildComponent? Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielPichot in a parent component I am calling the function and setting the state later I am passing the function to a child component togglecheckbox